# getting error about application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

Any help will be appreciated

```
Sub changeRange(startRange As Integer, endRange As Integer, rowNum As Integer, col As Integer)

    Select Case col
        Case 5
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Campus Summary #").Cells(rowNum, col).Formula = "=COUNTIF('TCP Export'!L" & startRange & ":L" & endRange & ", '>0')"
        Case 7
            Worksheets("Campus Summary #").curCell.Formula = "COUNTCase('TCP Export'!MstartRange:MendRange, '>0')"
        Case 9
            Worksheets("Campus Summary #").curCell.Formula = "COUNTCase('TCP Export'!NstartRange:NendRange, '>0')"
        Case 11
            Worksheets("Campus Summary #").curCell.Formula = "COUNTCase('TCP Export'!OstartRange:OendRange, '>0')"
        Case 13
            Worksheets("Campus Summary #").curCell.Formula = "COUNTCase('TCP Export'!PstartRange:PendRange, '>0')"
        Case 15
            Worksheets("Campus Summary #").curCell.Formula = "COUNTCase('TCP Export'!QstartRange:QendRange, '>0')"
        Case 17
            Worksheets("Campus Summary #").curCell.Formula = "COUNTCase('TCP Export'!RstartRange:RendRange, '>0')"
        Case 19
            Worksheets("Campus Summary #").curCell.Formula = "COUNTCase('TCP Export'!SstartRange:SendRange, '>0')"
        Case 21
            Worksheets("Campus Summary #").curCell.Formula = "COUNTCase('TCP Export'!TstartRange:TendRange, '>0')"
        Case 23
            Worksheets("Campus Summary #").curCell.Formula = "COUNTCase('TCP Export'!UstartRange:UendRange, '>0')"
        Case 25
            Worksheets("Campus Summary #").curCell.Formula = "COUNTCase('TCP Export'!VstartRange:VendRange, '>0')"
        Case 27
            Worksheets("Campus Summary #").curCell.Formula = "COUNTCase('TCP Export'!WstartRange:WendRange, '>0')"
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you give a specific line here the VBA editor shows the error. Also where is curCell declared?

Answer (score 2):

Some pointers:

1. I find your error confusing initially because there is no `.curCell` method/property of `Worksheet` object. You are using this where I would expect to find `.Range` or `.Cells`.
2. When using `.Cells`, or indeed `.Range`, neither row nor column reference can be 0.
3. It is misleading to have range in the name of variables passed as integers.
4. Finally, you want `Long` rather than `Integer` to avoid potential overflow.

Comment: Cracked it. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

## Tricky Tricky

```
Sub changeRange(startRange As Integer, endRange As Integer, _
    rowNum As Integer, col As Integer)

  Const cStrWs1 As String = "Campus Summary #"
  Const cStrWs2 As String = "TCP Export"
  Const cStrCase As String = "5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27"
  Const cStrColumn As String = "L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W"
  Const cStr1 As String = "COUNTIF('"
  Const cStr2 As String = "'!"
  Const cStr3 As String = ":"
  Const cStr4 As String = "," & Chr(34) & ">0" & Chr(34) & ")"

  Dim vntCase As Variant
  Dim vntColumn As Variant

  Dim i As Integer

  vntCase = Split(cStrCase, ",")
  vntColumn = Split(cStrColumn, ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(vntCase)
      If col = CInt(Trim(cStrCase(i))) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWs1).Cells(rowNum, col).Formula _
            = cStr1 & cStrWs2 & cStr2 & Trim(vntColumn(i)) & startRange & _
            cStr3 & Trim(vntColumn(i)) & endRange & cStr4
        Exit For
      End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It would appear this doesn't solve the `curCell` issue that OP is trying to do. Seems like should be a different logic for col=5 than the rest

Comment: @MacroMarc: I think he just could not place his issue into words, so in the first line he showed the last thing he did while he didn't change the other lines for us to easier find the answer to his trouble. I might be tripping here, but for me it has to be the answer, at least close. BTW I started the answer with the first logic ignored thinking the same as you, but as I was finishing they arrays etc. it reveled itself to me.

Comment: @MacroMarc: Something like this: Look, I did this in line 1, but it doesn't work. Try to fix it and while you're at it, apply the same logic to the other lines. He almost made it, but the double quotes in the COUNTIF function put the last nail into his coffin.

Comment: agree the OP should be more specific.